# Facebook API login returns The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I try to make a simple Facebook login, but when I use the login URL it gives me the error:

> Can't load URL
> The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

In my app's Basic App Settings I filled in **mysite.nl**.
In my app's Advanced App Settings (Share Redirect Allow List) I filled in **mysite.nl**.

So that should be alright. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The URL that I generated is:

> https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=https://mysite.nl&state=12345

So that looks alright too I guess.

Tried Googling but unfortunately I found no solution.

I use the latest API which is v18.0.

When creating the app I chose for:

> Allow people to log in with their Facebook account
> Our most common use case. A secure, fast, and convenient way for users to log into your app, and for your app to ask users for permission to access their data.

When I use the Graph API Explorer and press the button "Generate Access Token" it does work.

Hope someone can help me out with this matter.

Comment: You also need to have the "Website" platform set up, and your redirect_uri must be entered into the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" field under the Facebook Login settings.